# What is the correct way to reference relational tables in Google big query?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to achieve the following in goggle big query however struggling with syntax in Standard SQL Dialect

```html
SELECT DB.Table1.Key1,DB.Table3.Name ]
Where Table1.Key1=Table2.Key1, Table2.Key2=Table3.Name
```

Where the below is an abstract of the  tables

```html
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Tabel 1 |Table 2    |Table 3    |
| key1(PK)| Key1(FK)  | Key2(FK)  |
|         | Key2(PK)  | Name      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

```html
SELECT key   
FROM `DB.Table1`   
union DISTINCT 
SELECT key, Key2
from
`DB.Table2`
union DISTINCT 
SELECT Key2
from`DB3`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use standard sql mode try like below by using join

```
SELECT Table1.Key1,Table3.Name
from Table1 join Table2
on  Table1.Key1=Table2.Key1 
join Table3 on Table2.Key2=Table3.Name
```